# Minimum-weight disjoint union of perfect matchings

Tags: counterexamples, perfect-matchings

Is there a counter example or proof for the claim that the lightest edge-disjoint union of a pair of perfect matchings contains the edges of the lightest perfect matching in a finite complete graph with $2n$ vertices and positive edge-weights?

Comment: The context here is a weighted graph?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, sorry if that isn't clear from the question; I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should give a counterexample:
[image]

Make the black edges cost 1, green edges cost 2, and purple edges cost 1 billion. Make all other edges cost 10 trillion so we can safely ignore them (thus this counter example also works for the version of the question concerning complete *bipartite* graphs).

The minimum perfect matching is the three black edges, but any edge-disjoint union of two perfect matchings that contains the black edge perfect matching also must contain at least one purple edge. Whereas you can for instance instead get an edge-disjoint union of two perfect matchings that's the 4 green edges plus the bottom and top black edges.

Comment: Very nice! The simplest things are the best in life, that's why they're so hard to find.